# How to join on spatial functions in Peewee?

Tags: postgis, peewee

I'm struggling with figuring out how to join a table in Peewee based on a fairly common table postgis pattern. I need to join a table based on a postgis function (st_contains). I imagine it would look something like:

```
Station.select().join(Location, on=fn.ST_Intersects(Station.geom, Location.geom)).where(Location.name == 'Ravenswood')
```

The above query, if supported, would return all Stations in the Location named Ravenswood. The equivalent SQL would be:

```
SELECT station.name, station.district, station.line
FROM station INNER JOIN location ON ST_Intersects(station.geom, loc.geom)
WHERE location.name = 'Ravenswood';
```

Unfortunately my experiments all seem to end with this abbreviated traceback:

```
File "/Users/j.../python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1555, in generate_joins
left_field = field.to_field
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_field'
```

Does peewee support this? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Peewee's join generation checked for expressions but not function calls. I have fixed this bug in 61034c569e9679832327332aee0348a57a2b990c . If you use peewee master you should be able to run the query now.

Answer (score 5):

Peewee's join generation checked for expressions but not function calls. I have fixed this bug in [61034c5](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/61034c569e9679832327332aee0348a57a2b990c) (released in v2.6.1). If you use peewee master you should be able to run the query now.